# Expanded form of product of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, closed-form

I have the following polynomial:
$$f(x)=\prod_{i\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times} \left((x+\zeta_n^i)^n-(n+1)\right)$$
Here, $\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i/n}$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity.

I want a "closed form" for it, meaning:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i =0}^{\varphi(n)n} a_i x^i$$
Where $\varphi(n)n$ is the degree of $f$.
I've tried what seems "standard", in applying binomial theorem:

$$f(x) = \prod_{i\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}\left(\sum_{j = 0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j(\zeta_n^i)^{n-k}-(n+1)\right)$$
It seems like the next step is probably to apply:
$$\prod_{i = 0}^n\sum_{j = 0}^m a_{i,j} = \sum_{e\in\{1,\dots,m\}^n}\prod_{i = 0}^n a_{i,e_i}$$
This seems quite difficult though.
Can someone suggest how to move forward with this?

For those interested, $f$ is the defining polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n,(n+1)^{1/n})$ as a number field, which I'm interested in doing Sage computations in quickly. Hopefully, an explicit form of $f$ will help this.

Answer (score 1):

Since if you can find
$f^{(k)}(0)$
for all $k$,
you can get the polynomial,
a possibility would be
to get these derivatives.

One way might be
to apply the product rule
for differentiating.

If
$g(x)
=\prod_{k=1}^m f_m(x)
$
then
$\ln g(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^m \ln f_m(x)
$
so
$(\ln g(x))'
=\dfrac{g'(x)}{g(x)}
=\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{ f_m'(x)}{f_m(x)}
$
so
$g'(x)
=g(x)\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{ f_m'(x)}{f_m(x)}
$.

Another possibility
is to look up
"nth derivative of composite function"
or
"faa di bruno's rule"
and see if these can help.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.